# Знак ударения (в раскладке и не только)

Tags: словоупотребление, пунктуация, орфография, буква-ё, ударение

В современнном русском знак ударения поджидает примерно такая же судьба, что и букву ё. Тем не менее хотелось бы уточнить: предусмотрен ли это знак в  русской раскладке клавиатуры?

Если да, то каким магическим сочетанием клавиш оный знак вызывается?

О чем, на ваш взгляд, свидетельствует выход знака ударения из употребления?

Comment: Знак ударения отнюдь не выходит из употребления, он активно употребляется там, где он нужен — в словарях и учебниках.

Comment: Буква ё тоже совсем не выходит из употребления, а скорее наоборот входит :-). Её всё больше и больше печатают.

Comment: В каких текстах?

Comment: Нету знака ударения в обычной раскладке, хорошо что хоть ё имеем. В старину всё было иначе: http://rk86.com/frolov/i1030m-3.jpg

Comment: Ещё проще добавить в автоисправления замену а' на á, а также все остальные гласные. Хотя, возможно в ворде они уже включены по умолчанию.

Comment: Cравнение некорректно. "ё" - часть алфавита, знак ударения - вспомогательный символ (в отличие, скажем, от испанского, где si и sí это разные слова).

Comment: Интересно что в XIV веке начали писать тексты с ударениями, благодаря чему теперь можно узнать как в те времена в словах стояли ударения. Но такое массовое использование ударений закончилось в XVII веке. Так что "выход знака ударения из употребления" вне учебной литературы произошел несколько веков назад.

Comment: For historical reason I'm not deleting this but by all means it's not about Russian language per se.

Answer (score 9):

Я бы хотел знать, откуда взялось мнение, что ударение выходит из употребления.  Этот знак очень даже используется.  Этот знак можно ввести на русской клавиатуре, несмотря на то, что он не показан ни на одной из клавиш.

На маке для того, чтобы вводить этот знак, нужно пойти в System Preferences -> Language and Text -> Input Sources и поставить птичку на *Unicode Hex Input* - это делается один раз.  Далее, когда нужно поставить этот знак, ставите курсор после ударной гласной, переключаетесь на этот unicode hex input и, держа нажатой кнопку *alt*, нажимаете `0301` - и бу́дет вам сча́стье.

На виндах нужно, держа нажатой клавишу Alt, нажать "+" на цифровой клавиатуре, после чего нажать `0301` - и, опя́ть же, бу́дет вам сча́стье.

Да, согласен, что это не самое весёлое развлечение - но оно работает :)

**Добавлено:** Чтобы ввести знак ударения на линункс (и вообще в большинстве X-Windows программ), нужно, прижав Ctrl+Shift, набрать u0301, после чего отпустить Ctrl и Shift - и там то́же бу́дет вам сча́стье.

Comment: 0301 - шестнадцатеричное число, на винде его надо в десятичном виде набирать, т. е. 769, как я и писал.

Comment: @YellowSky На винде можно [Alt 769 (numeric)] либо [Alt +(numeric) 0301 (normal)]

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+u - это не для X Window, а только для GTK приложений. В Опере есть свой метод: набра́ть 0301, а пото́м нажа́ть Ctrl+Shift+X

Comment: Для X се́рвера мо́жно настро́ить Compose key, то́лько с ним не полу́чится ста́вить ударе́ние для ы, э, я

Comment: @WhiteWind Мы́  над э́тим посмея́лись. Это у вас шрифт неправильный.

Comment: "Alt +" в Windows по умолчанию не работает, нужны манипуляции с реестром. В MS Word можно ввести шестнадцатеричный код и нажать Alt+X.

Comment: Все эти цифровые комбинации в жизни не мог запомнить. Пока соображу, что да как, уже десять раз копипастой из Википедии стырю. Так и живу. И не стыжусь!

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ - скачать и установить [раскладку Бирмана](http://ilyabirman.ru/projects/typography-layout/), в ней есть не только ударения, но и много других служебных символов. Вот [рецензия](http://www.slovomania.ru/dnevnik/2009/01/05/typolayout-2/) на неё. Если нет желания её качать и ставить, можно последовать советам из [другой статьи](http://www.slovomania.ru/dnevnik/2007/08/11/how-to-use-stress-sign/), но это хлопотнее, и не во всех программах работает (комментарии там тоже почитайте). Стандартная комбинация Alt+769 (цифры набираются на цифровой клавиатуре справа) работает не везде, в Opera и MS Word работает, а, например, в Chrome - нет...

Comment: Поддерживаю. Да и раскладка Бирмана ставится за секунды.

Answer (score 2):

Ввести — это еще половина проблемы. Лично я предпочитаю использовать для этого composing sequence из двух обратных апострофов (`) на QWERTY и соответственно двух знаков «ё» на ЙЦУКЕН. Для чего пользователю Иксов, у которого composing уже настроен, достаточно прописать

```
<Multi_key> <grave> <grave> : "́" U0301 # COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_io> <Cyrillic_io> : "́" U0301 # COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT
```

в `~/.XCompose`.

Теперь, начав использовать знак ударения, он столкнется с тем, что:

- Ни в одной однобайтовой кодировке для русского языка (CP-1251, КОИ-8) его нет. Да, однобайтовые кодировки умирают, но кое-где до сих пор держаться.
- В некоторых шрифтах его тоже нет. Например, в микрософтской Georgia. И хорошо, если fallback font окажется хотя бы немного нее похожим.
- В некоторых шрифтах он есть так, что лучше бы не было. Например, в микрософтовской же Verdana — одним из самых популярных шрифтов Интернета. В ней знак ударения смещается на букву вправо:

[image: Verdana]

- Даже не стоит пытаться расставлять ударения в тексте, который будут читать моноширным шрифтом. Будет что-нибудь из этого:

[image: Mono]

Так что, боюсь, еще не скоро знак ударения будет поджидать судьба точек над «ё» — превращение из графического элемента, характерного разве что для детских книжек, в используемый повсеместно.

Comment: Хорошее описание технической стороны простановки ударений. Сравнение с ё по-моему не очень уместно. Ё это буква алфавита, а ударение - особая метка над буквой. И сомневаюсь что ударение будет когда-либо использоваться повсеместно.

Comment: Спасибо, Artemix. Но аналогии с буквой «ё» все-таки проводил автор вопроса, я же полностью с вами солидарен — не надо сравнивать общее с частным. «Ё» целиком если и можно с чем-то сопоставлять, то с графемами «а́», «е́», «и́», «о́», «у́», «ы́», «э́», «ю́», «я́» по отдельности. Каждая из них имеет свою вероятность войти в широкое употребление.