# What are all the times where "е" changes to "ё"?

Tags: история-языка, фонология, буква-ё

I don't know if this was asked before but I never saw it in search, so I'll just ask it.

Can someone list all the situations where "е" would be changed to "ё" ?
Like maybe after 2 vowels or if the word is in a certain condition or what?

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer for Russian language learners**

There are no simple rules to detect where Russian letter *е* should be read as *ё* (i. e. /jo/ or /ʲo/), as well as there are no rules to detect which syllable is stressed. Use dictionaries.

**More detailed answer for native and near-native Russian speakers**

Если упрощенно и вкратце, то переход /e/ → /o/, который и отмечается точками над *ё*, в русском языке происходил при следующих условиях:

- переходящий гласный должен быть ударным: *сёстры*, но *сестра́*;
- этот звук должен соответствовать букве *е*, а не *ѣ* (ять): *всё [это]*, но *все́ [они]* (*всѣ*), исключение — *звёзды* (*звѣзды*);
- до него идет мягкий, шипящий или свистящий согласный звук: *ёмкий*, но *э́то*;
- а после — не идет мягкий согласный: *ёлка*, но *е́ль* (шипящий может: *тёща*);

Все вышеперечисленное, разумеется, относится ко времени перехода, а он окончательно завершился никак не позднее XV века. Отсюда *пе́рвый*, а не *пёрвый* — /rʲ/ здесь тогда был мягким; *фане́ра*, а не *фанёра* — это более позднее заимствование. Еще есть куча церковнославянизмов — заимствований достаточно древних для того, чтобы переход произошел, но старательно поддерживавшихся в исконном состоянии: *не́́бо* (ср. *нёбо*), *ле́в* (но *лёва*) и т. д.

Плюс, вне зависимости от твердости / мягкости последующего согласного *е́* / *ё* имеют свойство сохраняться при склонении: *берёза* /z/ → *на берёзе* /zʲ/; спряжении: *идёт* /t/ → *идёте* /tʲ/; иногда словообразовании: *зелёный* /n/ → *зелёненький* /nʲ/, *уроже́нец* /nʲ/ → *уроже́нка* /n/.

А на самом деле все еще несколько сложнее — переход происходил в несколько этапов, в частности, на первом этапе ударение значения не имело, и это было бы важно при объяснении украинского языка (например, почему *чолові́к*), но для великорусского этим можно пренебречь.

По всему видно, что носителю современного русского языка эти правила, как и многие другие окололингвистические знания, не вполне полезны — произношение большинства слов и так прекрасно ему известны, а сложные случаи проще проверить по словарю.

Comment: щ in тёща is soft

Answer (score 0):

I think it is quite opposite: “ё” changes to “е”. As we all know “ё” can only form a stressed syllable. When a word form changes that the syllable is no longer stressed (such as ёж - ежо́вый) the “ё” becomes the “е”. However, the opposite does not apply.

Comment: Consider marking a stressed syllable with an apostrophe - ó.

Comment: @naXa Please _never_ use Latin letters (ó) instead of Cyrillic ones (о́) just as you’ve done right now. Apart from this, your advice is very good, imho, it would be better as suggested edit.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Copied and pasted it from Dmitry's comment, because my keyboard contains neither Latin nor Cyrillic stressed keys

Comment: @cha How to type a stress mark see for instance [this question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1690/%d0%97%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be/2872#2872) on R.SE.

Answer (score -2):

`ё` can be changed to `е`, because the former is optional in the modern Russian. (*a text* in the more detailed part of [this answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/4312/2199) is a good example.)
If you really need such a list of words where `ё` is used take a look at this [Ё-vocabulary](http://www.yomaker.ru/yoslovar.htm). But if your aim is just to learn Russian you will find [this short list of words with `Ё`](http://bukva-yo.ru/spisok-slov.html) sufficient:

```
актёр
бёдра*
берёза
бурёнка
варёный
вёдро*
всё*
вёрткий
вёсны*
вёсла*
взлёт
влёт
вразлёт
гранёный
далёкий
дёрн
дирижёр
ёж
ёжик
ёжиться
ёлка
ёмкость
ёрничать
жёлтый
жёсткий
жёсткость
жжёный
залёт
зелёный
зёрна*
зёрнышко
излёт
калёный
клеёнка
клёв
клёвый
клён
клёпка
клёцки
кнёдли
ковёр*
колёсный
конёк
костёр
крёстный
лёгкий
лёгкость
лёд
лён
лётчик
овёс
огонёк
орёл
осёдлый
осёл
отвёртка
паникёр
пелёнка
пенёк
пёрышко
пёс
пёстрый
плёнка
плёс
поклёвка
подённый
подъём
позёмка
полёт
полётный
посёлок
приём
приёмка
самолёт
свёкор
сгущёнка
сгущёный
сёгун
сёдла*
сёмга
слёт
съёмка
таёжный
телёнок
тёмный
трёхъярусный
трёхколёсный
трёхзвёздочный
утёс
шофёр
четвёртый
чёлка
чёрствый
чёрт*
чёрточка
```

<sub>* The words that will change their meaning if you write `е` instead of `ё`.</sub>

As for verbs, [this](http://russkiy-na-5.ru/rules/93) can be taken as a rule:

> **§** В суффиксах и окончаниях глаголов, суффиксах отглагольных существительных, прилагательных и причастий после шипящих и `ч` под ударением пишется буква `ё`:
>
> `стереж[ёшь]`, `стереж[ёт]`, `береж[ёшь]`, `береж[ёт]`, `жж[ёшь]`, `жж[ёт]`, `туш<ён>ка`, `туш<ён>ый`, `сбереж<ённ>ый`, `сожж<ённ>ый`.

Refer to the [cha's answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/4305/2199) as a guide to situations where `ё` change to `е` is mandatory.